# Удаляется ли сборщиком мусора объект, находящийся в блоке if?

Tags: javascript, объекты, if, сборщик-мусора

Есть такой код:

```js
if (true) {
    let object = {
        name: 'object'
    }
    let a = 10;
}
```

Получается, что `if` - это не объект. Как `if` вообще может ссылаться на объект, находящийся внутри него? Я этого не понимаю...

**P. S.** Сами переменные никуда не удаляются сборщиком мусора после отработки блока `if`? К ним получается, просто нет доступа, так как у `let` блочная область видимости, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Когда к объекту нет никаких ссылок - он удаляется.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/garbage-collection#:~:text=%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%C2%AB%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%C2%BB%20(%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82,%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B.

Comment: @entithat на него как бы и в самом блоке `if` нет никаких ссылок

Comment: ну то он удалится

Comment: @entithat то есть объект создастся, потом браузер посмотрит, что на него никто не держит ссылку в "цепочке ссылок" - удалит объект, так?

Comment: так............

Comment: `Как if вообще может ссылаться на объект, находящийся внутри него?`. Функция — это не единственная синтаксическая конструкция в языке, порождающая специальный объект `LexicalEnvironment`. См.: [How is block scope managed in the lexical environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29410249), [Why do catch clauses have their own lexical environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15034864), [Explanation of `let` and block scoping with for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30899612).

Comment: @wololo спасибо за ссылки, обязательно ознакомлюсь) То есть, если вкратце, выходит, что любой (ну или практически любой) блок создает `lexical enviroment`?

Comment: Собственно цитата из ответа по первой приведённой ссылке: «`if (x) {let y = 5;}` ... block statements in ES6 means that each block has its own lexical environment. In the above example, a new lexical environment is created when the block (the body of the if statement) is evaluated.» Если по-русски, то да, блоки создают собственные лексические окружения.